# Converting image to grayscale in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How i can convert a normal image to Grayscale image in windows phone 8. Is there any provision for grayscale conversion is available in WritableBitmapEx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
try this extension method...

public static WriteableBitmap ToGrayScale(this WriteableBitmap bitmapImage)
{

    for (var y = 0; y < bitmapImage.PixelHeight; y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < bitmapImage.PixelWidth; x++)
        {
            var pixelLocation = bitmapImage.PixelWidth * y + x;
            var pixel = bitmapImage.Pixels[pixelLocation];
            var pixelbytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(pixel);
            var bwPixel = (byte)(.299 * pixelbytes[2] + .587 * pixelbytes[1] + .114 * pixelbytes[0]);
            pixelbytes[0] = bwPixel;
            pixelbytes[1] = bwPixel;
            pixelbytes[2] = bwPixel;
            bitmapImage.Pixels[pixelLocation] = BitConverter.ToInt32(pixelbytes, 0);
        }
    }

    return bitmapImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is a method, but you can convert it yourself. There are bunch of resources online on how to accomplish that. Start by reading [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/PicFx--Windows-Phone-Picture-Effects-Application--Part-1). One of the simpler methods could be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < oldBitmap.Pixels.Length; i++)
{
    var c = oldBitmap.Pixels[i];
    var a = (byte)(c >> 24);
    var r = (byte)(c >> 16);
    var g = (byte)(c >> 8);
    var b = (byte)(c);

    byte gray = (byte)((r * 0.3) + (g * 0.59) + (b * 0.11));
    oldBitmap.Pixels[i] = (a << 24) | (gray << 16) | (gray << 8) | gray;
}
```

It's simple, quick, and you convert it in-place.